# create a countif measure not impacted by filter in visual in powerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Need help in creating measures that will reflect the actual count of rows in the table when filtered.

Example:

| ID | RankC | RankA | Avg Diff | RankC_count | RankA_count | Avg Diff_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | AAA | XYZ | +01.00 to +01.25 | 5 | 6 | 4 |
| 1001 | AAA | ZY1 | +01.5.00 to +01.75 | 5 | 1 | 5 |
| 1002 | AAB | XYZ | +01.5.00 to +01.75 | 3 | 6 | 5 |
| 1003 | AAB | ZY2 | +01.5.00 to +01.75 | 3 | 1 | 5 |
| 1004 | AAB | XYZ | +01.00 to +01.25 | 3 | 6 | 4 |
| 1005 | AAA | XYZ | +01.00 to +01.25 | 5 | 6 | 4 |
| 1006 | AAA | ZY3 | +01.00 to +01.25 | 5 | 1 | 4 |
| 1007 | AAC | XYZ | +01.25.00 to +01.5 | 1 | 6 | 2 |
| 1008 | AAA | ZY4 | +01.25.00 to +01.5 | 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 1009 | AAZ | ZY4 | +01.5.00 to +01.75 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 1010 | ABY | XYZ | +01.5.00 to +01.75 | 1 | 6 | 5 |

The last 3 columns represent the count of each entry.  If I use the measure such as below, it provides the correct count.  However, when I use in the visual, filtering by ID, say ID 1000, I want it to show line 1 with 5,6, and 4 on the counts, instead of all 1.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any measure to give me the correct result?  say summarize the table first then do a lookup?
2. is creating a column the only choice?  I cannot create columns since I need 1000 of these calculated columns.  whereas using measure, I can create 1000 in one go.

Thanks for any help.

```
AverageDiff_Count =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER ( '28Jun_1973', [Average Diff] = '28Jun_1973'[Average Diff] )
    )
)
```

Comment: Apology for the table as it does not allow to post if not considered as code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ALL](https://dax.guide/all/) function is useful here. It removes filter context so that it uses the whole table instead of just the part in the current filter context.

```
AvgDiff_Count =
VAR CurrAvgDiff = SELECTEDVALUE ( '28Jun_1973'[Avg Diff] )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER ( ALL ( '28Jun_1973' ), '28Jun_1973'[Avg Diff] = CurrAvgDiff )
    )
```

Comment: Awesome. You rock!

Comment: If this solves your problem, please accept it to mark your question as answered.